# doctrine merge data into a entity class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i want to update name if there is any new names available. So all the names are stored in the variable **$names**, now when i try to merge the data into my entity it always return an error that ---

Notice: Array to string conversion

what i am doing wrong, can anyone help me to fix this issue.

```
$names = Array ( [0] => 11.se [1] => 22.se [2] => aa.se [4] => all.se [31] => allb.se [55] => ggg.com [56] => kkk.se [57] => lll.se [58] => mmm.se [60] => qqq.se [88] => zzz.se [89] ...


    $data = new MyNames(); // Entity class
    $data->setName($names); // set the names

    $em->merge($data); // merge the new names
    $em->flush();
```

Entity class myclass--

```
/**
 * MyNames
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MyNames
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

Comment: Probably `setName($name)` requires a string, not an array of string. You could foreach over the array or change the Entity, e.g. create `setNames(array $names)`. You probably should expand your question with the source for `class MyNames`

Answer (score 0):

Does the property `$name` hold a single name or multiple names? If it only holds 1 name the class should probably be renamed to `MyName`.

If `$name` has only 1 name, you can do the following:

```
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $data = new MyNames();
    $data->setName($name;
    $em->merge($data);
}
$em->flush();
```

Posted as answer, because it's too long for comment:

If `$name` should hold all the names from your array you could do something like:

```
$data->setName(implode(',', $data));
```

You don't provide much info, so there might be catch somewhere. I assume the class is just a simplified example. because it doesn't make much sense. Maybe you can provide a context, e.g. what the name is used for, what other data is in your class. That would help tremendously in giving a better answer.